# javascript if condition not executing all commands

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm having one little iritating problem. I have simple if condition in javascript code.
It goes something like this:

```
if (istinito) 
{  
   alert ('123');
   document.getElementById('obavestavanje').value="Pobedi "+ime_igraca+"!!!"; 
   kraj=true;
}
```

Alert apears when istinito=true, but element with id="obavestenje" never get its value, and variable kraj never is set to true. Variable kraj is global variable, and there are no conflicts with other parts of the JS code.
Any ideas why code stops after alert?

Comment: Does the console show any error message? Is the id really correct?

Comment: Do the values get applied once you click ok on the alert box?

Comment: Is `#obavestavanje` an html input?

Comment: What type of element has the ID obavestavanje? Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Where does the `ime_igraca` variable comes from ?

Comment: Yup, id is correct, and there are no error message.

Comment: Can you set up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If you're seeing the alert but nothing else, either an element with the ID of `obavestavanje` doesn't exist on your page  (`document.getElementById("obavestavanje") === null`) or `ime_igraca` is undeclared (`typeof ime_igraca === "undefined"`).

Comment: are you sure `ime_igraca` has a value?

Comment: Your code says `obavestavanje` but you speak of `obavestenje`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Keep Document ready in mind? make sure dom is loaded before calling this code.

Comment: @troy No. I've put alert box just to test the if condition.

Comment: It's working here http://jsfiddle.net/a2da6/4/.

Comment: id obavestenje, and variable ime_igraca are used in the same code for other notifications, and they work. For example, after that if statement I have: else {document.getElementById('obavestavanje').value="Izgubi "+ime_igraca+"!!!"; kraj=true;} And it works when it should.

Answer (score 0):

First advice i could give you: 
Use more console logging for debugging. Almost any modern browser got a console to debug and other things.

```
if (istinito) {
    console.log("i am here");    
}
```

from that same console you can also execute commands. Those dom manipulations are easily done from the console. just run them and see if it works.

the code:

```
document.getElementById('obavestavanje').value = "some value"
```

looks ok. nothing wrong with it. i guess you don't have an element with id "obavestavanje" ?

Comment: I do have id "obavestavanje", it works in other parts of code. But I'm more concerned with variable kraj... I'll listen to your advice and use console. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `document.getElementById('obavestavanje')` is returning null. You are trying to de-reference the null reference by using document.getElementById('obavestavanje')**.value** which results in null pointer exception. If you look into the console, you should see some exception being raised. It is always a good idea to check if the document.getElementById() is returning a valid object before trying to dereference it.

e.g.

```
if (istinito) 
{  
   alert ('123');
   element = document.getElementById('obavestavanje')
   if(element){
      element.value="Pobedi "+ime_igraca+"!!!"; 
   }
   kraj=true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Suresh for your answer.  I'm more concerned with variable kraj which is false after this code. I will try to look into the console. Again, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is okay. And you are sure you have an element by id 'obavestavanje'. Could you please tell what element is it? Is it a button, textbox or someting like that?

Also the String in the "Pobedi "+**ime_igraca**+"!!!" , what is 'ime_igraca'? Is it a variable and if it is have you defined this variable somewhere?

Or did you mean to give the value "Pobedi ime_igraca !!!" ??

Thanks
Ranis MK